# How to add Add Image in first of the lazyrow in Jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

How to add Add Stories in first of the lazyrow(like instagram, facebook stories) using Jetpack compose?[image]

I posted image also

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your issue?

Comment: I want to add (add story design) as first item in lazyrow following by normal list items. How to achieve this

Comment: Use the item and items functions in your LazyColumn